# Python 3: 3 for-cycles parallel calculation

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, calculation, gil

I need to understand, how to perform fast calculations on Python 3.

I have read different web sites about GIL, `multiprocessing`, `Pool`, `Pool.map()`, but I don`t understand how to use these instruments for my task, which I post after this text. This task is intentionally simple (before doing something useful, I want to be able to do it fast), and I solved it by a single-process, traditional solution.

How to solve it by `multiprocessing` and to get small calculation time?

I need to get parallel processing for the final group of `for`-cycles, where `a.itog` values are initialized.

```
import numpy as np

def f_class(a, i, j, k):  # some long operation
    ans=np.cos(a.val1[i, j, k])*12.548-21.67*np.sin(a.val2[i, j, k])
    return ans

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val1=np.zeros((N, N, N))
        self.val2=np.zeros((N, N, N))
        self.itog=np.zeros((N, N, N))

if __name__=='__main__':
    global N              # Arrays size
    N = 100               
    a = A()               # Create exemplar of class A, named a
    for i in range(N):    # Initialize arrays of numbers into a
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(N):
                a.val1[i, j, k]=i
                a.val2[i, j, k]=2*j+k
    print(1)
    for i in range(N):    # Perform calculations by single-process way
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(N):
                # function is named 'f_class', because argument a is class
                a.itog[i, j, k]=f_class(a, i, j, k)
```

Comment: Before going into details, would you mind to explicitly state, what is considered in your context of processing "fast"? Thanks.

Comment: Using a big enough values of N, such as 300..1000, will cause my program to perform all calculations during some feasible time. In the future I`m going to modify the last section of 'for' cycles, so, calculation time for this section can be many hours or even more. The term 'fast' means that I need program code, which calculates the same values during time, which is at least twice smaller than time during which my program works now.

Comment: **Facts indeed do matter.** Frankly speaking, you told nothing useful. Let's be a way more quantitative, right? **[A]**: How many [ns] does your actual, not the mocked-up one above, `f_class()`-call indeed take per one call? What is your current run-time in [s] AS-IS for `N = 1000`, having there ~ 12 [GB] alloc'd / `A()` instance  ( having `.val1[N,N,N]` ~1E9 cells, `.val2[N,N,N]` ~1E9 cells, `.itog[N,N,N]` ~1E9 cells )? **[B]**: How many [GB]-s RAM does your processing platform operate with + how many ( CPUs,cpuCOREs ) has the host RTO on? So do not hesitate to update your post accordingly.

Comment: Since current run-time for N=200 is 17.2 s, the function f_class() requires (17.2/8) mcs = 2150 ns per one call. RAM size is 32 GB, and CPU has 8 cores. But could you tell why these details do matter? Universal algorithm for making calculations faster can not depend on all of this. I just need this algorithm.

Comment: **Sorry, "*I just need this algorithm.*" does not work here**. Without knowing resources none algorithmisation will work at any remarkable performance ( FYI, to have an idea of orders of magnitude a smart design can save -- a numerical process that was originally taking ~130+ hrs could be done in less than 3 minutes, if designed ultimately well ). But it takes both the hardware knowledge and the insights into using adequate processing tools.